# Detect only screenshot with FileObserver Android

Tags: android, screenshot, capture, detect

I am currently developing an application for Android and wanted to know how to detect a screenshot. I tried with FileObserver but the problem is that all events are detected ( when device goes into sleep, message, etc. ) . How to detect only screenshot ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 25):

How did you use `FileObserver` to detect screen shot creation? When using `FileObserver`, only monitor the file creation event in screen shot directory.

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
            + File.separator + "Screenshots" + File.separator;
    Log.d(TAG, path);

    FileObserver fileObserver = new FileObserver(path, FileObserver.CREATE) {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            Log.d(TAG, event + " " + path);
        }
    };

    fileObserver.startWatching();
```

Don't forget to declare corresponding permissions to access content in SD card.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Another solution to detect the screen shot is using `ContentObserver`, because there will be a record inserted to the system media database after screen shot. Following is the code snippet using `ContentObserver` to monitor the event. By using `ContentObserver`, it's not necessary to declare `write/read external storage` permissions, but you have to do some filters on the file name to make sure it's a screen shot event.

```
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("content_observer");
    handlerThread.start();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()) {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            true,
            new ContentObserver(handler) {
                @Override
                public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "deliverSelfNotifications");
                    return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                    super.onChange(selfChange);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChange " + uri.toString());
                    if (uri.toString().matches(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString() + "/[0-9]+")) {

                        Cursor cursor = null;
                        try {
                            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
                            }, null, null, null);
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                final String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                final String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                                // TODO: apply filter on the file name to ensure it's screen shot event
                                Log.d(TAG, "screen shot added " + fileName + " " + path);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (cursor != null)  {
                                cursor.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
                }
            }
    );
```

**Updated**

If you use second method, you have to request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` after version Android M, otherwise it will throw `SecurityException`. For more information how to request runtime permission, refer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: `FileObserver` doesn't work for me, but the ContentProvider way works, although need some modification. We need query image content with `DESC` order, to get the latest image that cause this `onChange` event.

Comment: ContentObserver giving exception
"java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=31855, uid=10341 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()", if the Storage Permission is not granted at MARSHMELLOW

Comment: @shanrais Yes, you should check and ask the runtime permission at Android M. Please infer http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html for more information.

Comment: "it's not necessary to declare write/read external storage permissions"
I found this statement ambiguous in your answer.

Comment: @shanrais OK, I have updated the answer, thanks for your correctness.

Comment: The first code snippet didn't work because the `path` String needed to end with the `File.separator`character. I have edited that code snippet accordingly. :-)

Comment: For the second code snippet, you can add the necessary permission to your manifest file for Marshmallow and above to: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:minSdkVersion="23" />`

Comment: You also need to specify `fileObserver`as a field - as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32409712/1617737 . You can create it in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Is it also possible to get the content of the screenshot i.e the image. in addition to detecting that a screenshot was taken ?

Comment: @ChetanGowda Depending on your chosen method, you would simply use the reference to the `File` or `MediaStore` entry and treat it like any other.

Comment: @alijandro Using ContentObserver in above answer, I am getting below warning message on Pixel 4 and screenshot not detected.

"CAM_SpecTypeMeta: Ignoring metadata for file which is not an image /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20200826-223441.png"

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

I have improve the code from alijandro's comment to make it easy-to-use class and fix the problem when content observer has detect the image from camera (should be screenshot image only). Then wrap it to delegate class for convenient to use.

---

• ScreenshotDetectionDelegate.java

```
public class ScreenshotDetectionDelegate {
    private WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakReference;
    private ScreenshotDetectionListener listener;

    public ScreenshotDetectionDelegate(Activity activityWeakReference, ScreenshotDetectionListener listener) {
        this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activityWeakReference);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void startScreenshotDetection() {
        activityWeakReference.get()
                .getContentResolver()
                .registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, contentObserver);
    }

    public void stopScreenshotDetection() {
        activityWeakReference.get().getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(contentObserver);
    }

    private ContentObserver contentObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
            return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
            super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
            if (isReadExternalStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                String path = getFilePathFromContentResolver(activityWeakReference.get(), uri);
                if (isScreenshotPath(path)) {
                    onScreenCaptured(path);
                }
            } else {
                onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission();
            }
        }
    };

    private void onScreenCaptured(String path) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onScreenCaptured(path);
        }
    }

    private void onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission() {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission();
        }
    }

    private boolean isScreenshotPath(String path) {
        return path != null && path.toLowerCase().contains("screenshots");
    }

    private String getFilePathFromContentResolver(Context context, Uri uri) {
        try {
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
            }, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                cursor.close();
                return path;
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean isReadExternalStoragePermissionGranted() {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activityWeakReference.get(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public interface ScreenshotDetectionListener {
        void onScreenCaptured(String path);

        void onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission();
    }
}
```

---

• ScreenshotDetectionActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public abstract class ScreenshotDetectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ScreenshotDetectionDelegate.ScreenshotDetectionListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 3009;

    private ScreenshotDetectionDelegate screenshotDetectionDelegate = new ScreenshotDetectionDelegate(this, this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkReadExternalStoragePermission();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        screenshotDetectionDelegate.startScreenshotDetection();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        screenshotDetectionDelegate.stopScreenshotDetection();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    showReadExternalStoragePermissionDeniedMessage();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenCaptured(String path) {
        // Do something when screen was captured
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission() {
        // Do something when screen was captured but read external storage permission has denied
    }

    private void checkReadExternalStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestReadExternalStoragePermission();
        }
    }

    private void requestReadExternalStoragePermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
    }

    private void showReadExternalStoragePermissionDeniedMessage() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Read external storage permission has denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

---

• MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ScreenshotDetectionActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenCaptured(String path) {
        Toast.make(this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission() {
        Toast.make(this, "Please grant read external storage permission for screenshot detection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello ,This code working for me,but have issue in some device.can you give   some solution.?

Comment: @bhoomika Do you have any info about these devices?

Comment: Android 6.0 at Nexus 7 gives content://media/external/images/media as uri in onChange, which can't be properly resolved to the file path

Comment: I am using this code to get the screenshot image but in Marshmallow I didn't get full content uri from onChange method. Can you please help me to get full uri ?

Comment: This solution is still working on Android 11, but it should be noted that "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" flag does not exist any more. So you must modify the code to only call "onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission".

Answer (score 1):

You can create FileObserver that only monitors screenshot directory plus only trigger events for file or directory creation.
For more information click [here](http://theengineerscafe.com/create-fileobserver-android/).

Answer (score 0):

I made a [git project for Android screenshot detection using Content Observer](https://github.com/SinsangMarket/ASS).

It is working fine from API 14 to the most recent version (at the time of posting).

1.ScreenShotContentObserver .class 
(original screenshot delete -> inform screenshot taken and give screenshot bitmap )

```
public class ScreenShotContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID
    };
    private static final long DEFAULT_DETECT_WINDOW_SECONDS = 10;
    private static final String SORT_ORDER = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

    public static final String FILE_POSTFIX = "FROM_ASS";
    private static final String WATERMARK = "Scott";
    private ScreenShotListener mListener;
    private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
    private String lastPath;

    public ScreenShotContentObserver(Handler handler, ContentResolver contentResolver, ScreenShotListener listener) {
        super(handler);
        mContentResolver = contentResolver;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        Log.e(TAG, "deliverSelfNotifications");
        return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
    }

    @Override
    synchronized public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            //above API 16 Pass~!(duplicated call...)
            return;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "[Start] onChange : " + selfChange);
        try {
            process(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            Log.e(TAG, "[Finish] general");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "[Finish] error : " + e.toString(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    synchronized public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
        Log.e(TAG, "[Start] onChange : " + selfChange + " / uri : " + uri.toString());

        if (uri.toString().startsWith(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString())) {
            try {
                process(uri);
                Log.e(TAG, "[Finish] general");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "[Finish] error : " + e.toString(), e);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "[Finish] not EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI ");
        }
    }

    public void register() {
        Log.d(TAG, "register");
        mContentResolver.registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, this);
    }

    public void unregister() {
        Log.d(TAG, "unregister");
        mContentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(this);
    }

    private boolean process(Uri uri) throws Exception {
        Data result = getLatestData(uri);
        if (result == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "[Result] result is null!!");
            return false;
        }
        if (lastPath != null && lastPath.equals(result.path)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "[Result] duplicate!!");
            return false;
        }
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        if (matchPath(result.path) && matchTime(currentTime, result.dateAdded)) {
            lastPath = result.path;
            Uri screenUri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString() + "/" + result.id);
            Log.e(TAG, "[Result] This is screenshot!! : " + result.fileName + " | dateAdded : " + result.dateAdded + " / " + currentTime);
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mContentResolver, screenUri);
            Bitmap copyBitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            int temp = mContentResolver.delete(screenUri, null, null);
            Log.e(TAG, "Delete Result : " + temp);
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onScreenshotTaken(copyBitmap, result.fileName);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "[Result] No ScreenShot : " + result.fileName);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private Data getLatestData(Uri uri) throws Exception {
        Data data = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = mContentResolver.query(uri, PROJECTION, null, null, SORT_ORDER);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID));
                String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                long dateAdded = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED));

                if (fileName.contains(FILE_POSTFIX)) {
                    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID));
                        fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                        dateAdded = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED));
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                data = new Data();
                data.id = id;
                data.fileName = fileName;
                data.path = path;
                data.dateAdded = dateAdded;
                Log.e(TAG, "[Recent File] Name : " + fileName);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    private boolean matchPath(String path) {
        return (path.toLowerCase().contains("screenshots/") && !path.contains(FILE_POSTFIX));
    }

    private boolean matchTime(long currentTime, long dateAdded) {
        return Math.abs(currentTime - dateAdded) <= DEFAULT_DETECT_WINDOW_SECONDS;
    }

    class Data {
        long id;
        String fileName;
        String path;
        long dateAdded;
    }
}
```

2. Util.class

   ```
   public static void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String title) throws Exception {
       OutputStream fOut = null;
       title = title.replaceAll(" ", "+");
       int index = title.lastIndexOf(".png");
       String fileName = title.substring(0, index) + ScreenShotContentObserver.FILE_POSTFIX + ".png";
       final String appDirectoryName = "Screenshots";
       final File imageRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), appDirectoryName);
       imageRoot.mkdirs();
       final File file = new File(imageRoot, fileName);
       fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
       fOut.flush();
       fOut.close();

       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "XXXXX");
       values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "description here");
       values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
       values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, file.hashCode());
       values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, file.getName());
       values.put("_data", file.getAbsolutePath());
       ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
       Uri newUri = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
       context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
   }
   ```