# FileObserver doesn't work

Tags: android, fileobserver

In my Android app I want to detect events from directory. Here is code:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "test2";
    Log.d("test", "path is " + path);

    FileObserver fileObserver = new FileObserver(path, FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS) {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            Log.d("test", "event dectect " + event + " " + path);
        }
    };

    fileObserver.startWatching();
```

I copy new file to the directory. But I don't get any event. Please show me where I made a mistake.

Comment: probably Activity is in Pause or Stop state when copying new file in directory. so try it by  copying file in directory from `adb shell` without minimizing Activity

Comment: I copied the new file using wife transfer ( I uploaded it from my computer). So I don't think the Activity is in Pause or Stop.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot use a local variable to store your FileObserver, it would be available for garbage collection after the method is run.

> Warning: If a FileObserver is garbage collected, it will stop sending
>   events. To ensure you keep receiving events, you must keep a reference
>   to the FileObserver instance from some other live object.

Solution: save it to a field.

Answer (score 1):

Adding storage permission worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that FileObserver does not work on symbolic links, which is what is returned by Environment.getExternalStorage().

The trick for me was to resolve the links using File.getCanonicalPath()

Example:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExteranlStorage(), "myfile");
new FileObserver(file.getCanonicalPath()) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @user3219477's answer be sure to go in to Settings->Apps->YourApp and grant Storage permission if you aren't requesting it dynamically in your app.