# Xamarin iOS/Android: Detect Lockscreen /home screen click detection or swipe detection

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a mobile app using xamarin forms, is it possible to detect swipe gesture in android for screenshot or click of lock screen or home screen ?

If it is possible via objective C/swift/java then it would also be possible through Xamarin.

Comment: iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352228/is-there-a-away-to-detect-the-event-when-ios-device-goes-to-sleep-mode-when-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android**

I do not believe you can setup a swipe gesture / click during the Lock Screen as it's a separate Activity in a different process(System app). You also can't replace the lock screen with a user application.

You can control some of this via the `Device Admin` API:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#lock

However that's only for the opposite of what you want(Probably to know if the user finished the lock screen).

You can instead listen for the `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` or the fairly new `ACTION_USER_UNLOCKED` broadcast via a `Broadcast Receiver`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT (API 3)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_UNLOCKED (API 24)

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot.html#notification

**iOS**

You can use `Darwin` Notifications - https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1666719-cfnotificationcenter

You can check the following events:

- `com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen` - When the screen goes blank (One of a few times it will)
- `com.apple.springboard.lockstate` - What state the lock is in(locked/unlocked)
- `com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete` - The device locked

[Is there a away to detect the event when iOS device goes to sleep mode (when the screen gets blackened)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352228/is-there-a-away-to-detect-the-event-when-ios-device-goes-to-sleep-mode-when-the)

[Lock Unlock events iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone)

Comment: Hi Jon,

I wanted swipe gesture for android before lock just to know if they are trying to screenshot the screen and lock button or home button on apple to know if they are trying to screenshot. I think Darwin notifications would help for iOS but can you shed some light for android's swipe gesture on active screen not locked screen ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621903/detect-only-screenshot-with-fileobserver-android